# Java duplicate elements in a list

Tags: java

I have the below program to find duplicate elements in a list. It works only for few elements in the list. I am breaking my head for the past 30 minutes, but I can't figure out my mistake :( Need some expert advise please!

```
public class CheckDuplicateInList {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1,2,1,4,1,2,3,4);
    checkDuplicateInList(lst);      
}

public static boolean checkDuplicateInList(List<Integer> intList) { 
    Map<Integer,Integer> ctMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<intList.size();i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<intList.size();j++) {
            if(intList.get(i) == intList.get(j)) {
                if(ctMap.containsKey(intList.get(i))) {
                        ctMap.put(intList.get(i),ctMap.get(intList.get(i))+1);  
                        break;
                }
                    else {
                        ctMap.put(intList.get(i),1);                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Duplicate elements in the List: ");
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> ctMapVals:ctMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(ctMapVals.getKey()+ " occurs " +ctMapVals.getValue()+ " times");
        }



    return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the program output -

```
Duplicate elements in the List: 
1 occurs 3 times
2 occurs 1 times
4 occurs 1 times
```

Why doesn't it give the correct result for 2, and 4? Please advise

Comment: why are you doing this:
int j=i+1; ? kind of limits the number of elements you compare

Comment: It's enouth to have just one loop and go through the list once increasing all the counters in the map.

Comment: You are `break`ing from the inner cycle inside the `if` statement.

Comment: make your second loop (using j) also start from 0, and add a break statement at the end of your else block.
or move it from within the if block to after the else block

Comment: Why have you guys downvoted? My code is not completely wrong, neither is my question non-sensical :( Come on guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a lot of extra code which are totally not required. Remove the inner `for` loop and the `if` statement which compares the `ith` and `jth` elements of the list.

The `containsKey()` method is enough to check if the number is already present in the `Map`. The `if(intList.get(i) == intList.get(j)) {` is just an overkill which is making your logic go for a toss.

```
for (int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++) {
    if (ctMap.containsKey(intList.get(i))) {
        ctMap.put(intList.get(i), ctMap.get(intList.get(i)) + 1);
    } else {
        ctMap.put(intList.get(i), 1);
    }
}
```

Output when using the above snippet:

```
Duplicate elements in the List: 
1 occurs 3 times
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 1 times
4 occurs 2 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static boolean checkDuplicateInList(List<Integer> intList) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> ctMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int e : intList) {
            if (ctMap.containsKey(e)) {
                ctMap.put(e, ctMap.get(e) + 1);
            } else {
                ctMap.put(e, 1);
            }
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop logic is wrong. It puts in map the value 1 for every match (it forgets that even without a match, there is one element at least) .. so correct code of for loop is:

```
 for(int i=0;i<intList.size();i++) {
        if(!ctMap.containsKey(intList.get(i))) {
             ctMap.put(intList.get(i),1);  
        }
        for(int j=i+1;j<intList.size();j++) {
            int  iKey = intList.get(i);
            int jKey = intList.get(j);
            if(iKey == jKey) {
                        ctMap.put(intList.get(i),ctMap.get(intList.get(i))+1);  
                        //break;


                }
            }
        }
```